# how to include jqplot in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jqplot

i am developing plugin where i am using jqplot for bar charts , i have done in the same way how they told in documentaion,but in wordpress its not working, but it is working in normal php, below is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/js/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/js/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/js/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/js/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/js/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/css/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
        var ticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
         
        plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
            // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
            animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                }
            },
            highlighter: { show: false }
        });
     
        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the debug console?

Comment: in wordpress its not working and its empty, i need it in wordpress, its working fine in normal php

Comment: Check your browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: $.jqplot is undefine its saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on how to properly [enqueue scripts](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) to ensure dependencies are met.  In your case, here is how I would enqueue the first script, jquery should already be loaded by WordPress unless you have removed it.  Also, move all your scripts under your child theme directory like I have done below.  Either that or create a proper plugin and nest them underneath that not in the root plugins directory like you have done.

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
     wp_register_script('jqplot', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.jqplot.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
     wp_enqueue_script('jqplot');
}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```